# struct changing existing records with ID match in array

Tags: c, struct

> Implement function '`update_age`' that changes the age ('`newage`') in one of the existing records in the array. The record to be changed is identified by the ID ('`p_id`'). If no record with matching ID are found, nothing is changed. The function returns 1, if a change was made, and 0 if no matching records were found. You can assume that there are no multiple entries with same ID.
>
> Implement function '`update_entrydate`' that changes the age ('`newdate`') in one of the existing records in the array. The record to be changed is identified by the ID ('`p_id`'). If no record with matching ID are found, nothing is changed. The function returns 1, if a change was made, and 0 if no matching records were found. You can assume that there are no multiple entries with same ID.

That's my assignment here so both of those update functions are pretty much the same and here I have tried to write them and I just can't understand what goes wrong here? Maybe I need some kind of a loop inside these functions? `main` has to remain the same and function `add_record` is good so do not mind about that.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Single animal entry
struct animal {
    char id[7]; // animal ID (6 characters) + terminating '\0'
    char *name; // animals name
    char *species; // animal species (string)
    unsigned char age; // animals age
    struct date entrydate;  // date of the animals arrival
};

struct animal *add_record(struct animal *array, unsigned int size, struct animal newanimal) 
{
    int n = size + 1;
    struct animal *newarray = realloc(array,  n*sizeof(*newarray));
    if (!newarray) {
        perror("realloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    array = newarray; 
    strcpy(array[n - 1].id, newanimal.id);
    array[n - 1].name = malloc(strlen(newanimal.name) + 1);
    strcpy(array[n - 1].name, newanimal.name);
    array[n - 1].species = malloc(strlen(newanimal.species) + 1);
    strcpy(array[n - 1].species, newanimal.species);
    array[n - 1].age = newanimal.age;
    array[n - 1].entrydate = newanimal.entrydate;
    return array;

int update_age(struct animal *array, unsigned int size, const char *p_id,
unsigned char newage) {

    for (int i = 0; !array; ++i) {
    if (strcmp(array[i], p_id)==0) {
        array[i] = newage;
        return 1
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
}

int update_entrydate(struct animal *array, unsigned int size, const char *p_id,
struct date newdate) {
    int n = size + 1;
    if (array[n-1].id == p_id) {
        array[n-1].entrydate = newdate;
        return 1;
    }
    if (array[n].id == p_id) {
        array[n].entrydate = newdate;
        return 1;
    }
    if (array[n + 1].id == p_id) {
        array[n + 1].entrydate = newdate;
        return 1;
    }
    if (array[n + 2].id == p_id) {
        array[n + 2].entrydate = newdate;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    /*making new animal zoo which I want to which all of them I need to
      add to array in function add_record*/

    struct animal zoo[] = {
        { "123456", "Winnie-the-Pooh", "Bear", 94,{ 1,1,1924 } },
        { "555666", "Eeyore", "Donkey", 92,{ 1,1,1926 } },
        { "773466", "Piglet", "Very Small Animal", 30,{ 31, 12, 2015 } },
        { "234567", "Roo", "Kangaroo", 5,{ 31, 12, 2015 } }
    };
    //this below is for the function add_record so do not mind
    struct animal *array = NULL;
    unsigned int len = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(zoo) / sizeof(struct animal); i++) {
        struct animal *newarray = add_record(array, len, zoo[i]);
        len++;
        array = newarray;
    }
    //from here starts the part of this question
    struct date day1 = { 0, 0, 0 };

    if (!update_age(array, len, "555666", 50))
        printf("failed '555666'\n");

    if (!update_age(array, len, "23456677", 3))
        printf("failed '234567', invalid id\n");

    if (!update_entrydate(array, len, "123456", day1))
        printf("failed '111111'\n");

    if (!update_entrydate(array, len, "999999", day1))
        printf("failed '234567', no course\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes you're going to need a loop that loops through `array` and locates the `struct animal` with the `id` of the animal that needs to be changed. In fact I would create a function `struct animal* locate_animal(char* id){ ... }` that returned a pointer to a `struct animal` if found (`NULL` if not found), and pass that pointer into your `update_*` functions. That will modularize functionality. `update_age` right now looks like a series of out-of-bounds accesses of `array`

Comment: `strcpy(array->id, newanimal.id);`  looks like it is copying data always into the first element of `array`.  I'd expect `array[size].id` or something like that.

Comment: @chux yea forgot to edit that, but that function wasn't the point:d

Comment: also, use [`strcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to compare strings,, `==` compares pointer values, not what you want here.

Comment: With `if (array[n].id == p_id)`, it is not clear that `array[n].id` has been assigned anywhere.  `array[n + 1].id` too.

Comment: @yano yea sorry forgot to say that I'm not allowed to do extra functions cause that struct animal is actually in header file which need to be unchanged, so I need to somehow loop it inside of these update functions

Comment: You can add functions without modifying the header file. If a stipulation of the assignment is "no new functions", that's stupid. The whole point of a function is to modularize functionality. A function should do one thing and do it well. But if you're not allowed to add new functions, you'll need to put identical searcher code in each `update_` function. You must find the animal you're dealing with before you can modify it.

Comment: @chux okay then I don't know what command will bring these ID's up

Comment: @yano yea true, but should I then go through every index of the array and see if it matches with the given ID?

Comment: yes, you must locate your animal (which is uniquely defined by its `id`) in order to figure out which animal you need to operate on. Since your data set isn't keyed with this `id`, you'll need to search through all your records until you find a match. This method of searching wouldn't efficiently scale well to a huge data set, but it certainly looks like your best/easiest option from what you've shown. Don't forget you must use a function like `strcmp` to find out if the `id`s match.

Comment: @yano  you mean something like that I edited to ´update_age function?´

Comment: something like that, yes, but `array[i]` is a `struct animal` type, you need to further differentiate what field you're talking about: `for (unsigned int i=0; i<size; i++){  if (strcmp(array[i].id, p_id) == 0){  array[i].age = newage; ...`

Comment: yea now I got it done, thank you super much! @yano

Comment: Please make an answer to your own question, in order to help others and in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.